# php code error :Parse error :syntax error,unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /var/www/html/shares/RSA.php

Tags: php, pear

this code

```
    $obj = &new Crypt_RSA($params, $wrapper_name, $error_handler);
```

have this error :

```
Parse error :syntax error,unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /var/www/html/shares/RSA.php
```

can anyone help ,thanks

Comment: And try this search on Google: _Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated_

Comment: FWIW the OP is using https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA which has long been abandoned.

Comment: this question is relevant for those of us who searched for this PHP error using the exact error syntax.  i believe it's a very useful question.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in the comments - using a reference in assignment is deprecated, so

```
$obj = &new Crypt_RSA($params, $wrapper_name, $error_handler);
```

should be

```
$obj = new Crypt_RSA($params, $wrapper_name, $error_handler);
```

(Remove the ampersand (`&`) before `new`).

Comment: thanks,but afther correct this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This change doesn't need any more code changes, but you may get new errors once this is fixed.

Comment: yes after change code this error occur :warning: Declaration of Digital_Signature::CreateSign() should be compatible with Crypt_RSA::createSign($document, $private_key = NULL, $hash_func = NULL)

Comment: This is probably related to the comment on your question about the Crypt_RSA not being maintained anymore.  That is way beyond the scope of this question and should be raised as a new question if you can't find an solution first.